# Iterative version of the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm with pivoting

Tags: graph-theory, pseudocode, non-recursive

I need much a correct pseudocode of [Bron–Kerbosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) algorithm (it enumerates all maximal cliques in an undirected unweighted graph). I need iterative (non-recursive) solution with a stack. And the version of the algorithm should be "with pivot" rather than "basic". (Both basic and pivot versions are considered in the Wikipedia article linked.)

I've [found an iterative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464232/868905) counterpart of the "basic" version, and it worked fine when I implemented it. But I need likewise the version "with pivot". To my shame, I find it always difficult for me to turn a recursive syntax into an iterative one. So can you help, please?

**Update.** Below is a pseudocode (iterative, with pivoting) I've picked, after an extensive search, from one article.

```
Iterative_BK_pivot(P, Q)
Stack := null
Stack.push({ }, P, { }, Q); /*i.e., initial R, P, X, Q (P is the collection of vertices; Q = ?)
while Stack is not empty do
     R, P, X,Q := Stack.pop();
     if P and X are both empty then
           report R as a maximal clique
     if Q is not empty then
          v := some vertex in Q
          Stack.push(R, P \ {v}, X ⋃ {v}, Q \ {v})
          choose a pivot vertex u of P (or of P ⋃ X) /*Say, the vertex with the largest degree of neighbours
          Stack.push(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v), P \ N(u))
```

When I tried to implement it, it did not work. Either the pseudocode is incorrect, or my undertanding of it, or my code.
After plenty of iterations, I am getting empty P in the line "choose a pivot vertex u" and so cannot pick u.
Plus to this, I am not sure how initial set Q should be defined at the beginning (one any vertex or all the vertices?).

I would really appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: This site is not a tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with a written algorithm. Your question, reads like "Can someone do this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to do this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: If you permit, @itprorh66, I would disagree. I don't see how my Q is off-topic (or badly put) while the one very similar, to that I'm linking to - and which was upvoted and answered, - happens to be on-topic. You maybe are implying that I had not made any attempt to try to solve the problem myself - then you are incorrect. I simply am finding my code isn't worthy to be published in the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My trial and error - after the comment left by @JanneKarila [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464232/868905) - produced me the following pseudocode. When implemented, it works correctly (i.e., always the same list of maximal cliques as the "basic" version). When the graph is dense, the "pivot" version is considerably faster.

```
Iterative_BK_pivot(P)
 Stack := null
 Stack.push({}, P, {}, {})
 while Stack is not empty do
     R, P, X, Q := Stack.pop()   //poped Q is a single vertex, the stored q
     if P and X are both empty then
        report R as a maximal clique
     else
        Choose* pivot vertex q from P ⋃ X  //the new q to store if P \ N(q) isn't empty
        if P \ N(q) is not empty then
           v := some vertex in P \ N(q) 
           Stack.push(R, P \ {v}, X ⋃ {v}, q)
           Stack.push(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v), q)

* Choose pivot vertex q from P ⋃ X - either the vertex with maximal
degree (i.e. number of neighbours) or a randomly chosen.
```